# Tkinter: What's the difference between grab and focus?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

In tkinter I am creating a `Toplevel` widget to prompt the user with "Are you sure you want to exit?" every time they try to exit my application. While this is happening, I want the `Toplevel` widget to have full focus of my application and the user to be unable to click anything on the root window, if possible.

While trying to figure out to do this, I discovered grabs and the ability to set the focus of the application. What is the difference between these two things?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus means that your window will receive all keyboard events until some other window gets the focus.  A grab tells the window manager that your window should have the focus until you explicitly tell it that it is allowed to take it away (ungrab).

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. However, when I use `toplevel.grab_set()`, I am still able to simply click on my root window to "highlight" it (it takes the focus -- not the focus as in `.focus_set()`, for example), but it doesn't accept keyboard and mouse events, which is half of what I want. The other half is to make it so the root window cannot be selected at all. That is, if you try to select the root window, nothing happens or something -- such as the `Toplevel` widget flashing -- happens to remind the user that it is open.

Comment: Sorry, the point of my previous comment is unclear and I can no longer edit it. I meant to ask if there was a way to achieve what I mentioned in the last two sentences. Thanks.

Comment: Bind "<Expose>" to a function that calls `toplevel.grab_set_global()`.  You may want to bind "<Alt-F4>" to a quit function, because the x button will no longer work.  Bind also "<ButtonPress>" to a function that takes the width and height of the window (`toplevel.winfo_width()` and `toplevel.winfo_height()`) and checks to see if `event.x` or `event.y` is negative or greater than the width or height respectively.  If it is outside of the window, call `toplevel.attributes("-alpha", 0.0)` and `toplevel.after(100, lambda: toplevel.attributes("-alpha", 1.0))`.

Comment: Ok I understand the part with the "<Expose>" (generated when the root window is exposed from behind the toplevel) and "<Alt-F4>" (standard app close key combination), but I am kind of confused with the call to `toplevel.attributes("-alpha", 0.0)`. What does that do? And thanks so much for your help by the way.

Comment: `toplevel.attributes("-alpha", num)` sets the opacity of the window to the fraction specified by num.  What is done when the mouse is clicked is that the window is set to be completely transparent, and then after 1/10 of a second (100 milliseconds) it is set to be completely opaque.  The result: the window blinks.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks! When I mentioned the `Toplevel` widget flashing, I meant it as an example to convey my point. Nonetheless, I may very well do that just because I know how to now.